# Safari web inspector not working with cordova in iOS12 and mac OS Mojave

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, ios12, safari-web-inspector

Recently I updated my device to the iOS12 (it's actually 12.0.1 now) and also my mac to the latest OS. Now, whenever I am trying to debug my Cordova app it will simply not show up in the Safari developer menu. The mobile browser works, its just Cordova not showing. This is happening only with the real device, in the simulator, it shows up. I followed a bunch of articles on how to reset the trust settings and even tried remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter and nothing. How can I get to the bottom of this? I am completely stuck and unable to continue with development.

I would like to mention that the app is using the wkwebview engine, not uiwebview and we never had this problem ever since we moved to the new engine for a least a year now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

download & try same in `Safari Technology Preview` https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Comment: I am marking this one as the answer so people know about the safari preview. However, please note that you have to wait for updates in case it still doesn't show up. That was my case, way before posting here. But after a week, the update came and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me too on iOS 12.2 and Mojave 10.14.3.  Sad that I had to install this but happy it is now working.

Comment: In my case safari showed the device but did not run the web inspector.
There is very little information about it, but this was the only thing that worked for me.
Although at the beginning it was not like that, I had to restart it several times because my device did not appear in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Go to you'r Phone settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> enable Web Inspector

then go to safari developer, you'r device will be appear there.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to restart Safari.

Lately it's been often that Cordova iOS debugger won't show in Safari, but I am able to fix it every time by completely quitting Safari and restarting it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that you sign your app with a ***development*** provisioning profile.